# MediaRecorder not saving files

Tags: java, android, camera, mediarecorder

I've had a look through the other people's encounters with this problem and have not found an adequate solution.
Like them, I followed the tutorial on camera functionality at: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html.
Everything listed below works perfectly to the point where I assume that the program has recorded video as I had intended. However, upon reviewing the video in the gallery, it has not appeared. I'm confused as there are no IOExceptions or other bugs present when connected for USB debugging. Strangely, upon removing the USB and plugging it in again, whenever that may be, either immediately or at some point days in the future, all of the previously recorded videos appear in the gallery. Clearly there something I have missed or some aspect of recording video that I am not aware of. Would appreciate any help or guidance, thank you.

Pertinent code is as follows, I'll post more if someone needs it.

Camera Activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

    mCamera = MainActivity.getCameraInstance();
    // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
    mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
    FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
    preview.addView(mPreview);
    button_capture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
    button_capture.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (isRecording) {
                        // stop recording and release camera
                        mMediaRecorder.stop();  // stop the recording
                        releaseMediaRecorder(); // release the MediaRecorder object
                        mCamera.lock();         // take camera access back from MediaRecorder

                        // inform the user that recording has stopped
                        button_capture.setText("Capture");
                        isRecording = false;
                    } else {
                        // initialize video camera
                        if (prepareVideoRecorder()) {
                            // Camera is available and unlocked, MediaRecorder is prepared,
                            // now you can start recording
                            mMediaRecorder.start();

                            // inform the user that recording has started
                            button_capture.setText("Stop");
                            isRecording = true;
                        } else {
                            // prepare didn't work, release the camera
                            releaseMediaRecorder();
                            // inform user
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
}

private boolean prepareVideoRecorder(){

    mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

    // Step 1: Unlock and set camera to MediaRecorder
    mCamera.unlock();
    mMediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);

    // Step 2: Set sources
    mMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
    mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

    // Step 3: Set a CamcorderProfile (requires API Level 8 or higher)
    mMediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));

    // Step 4: Set output file
    mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(MediaCapture.getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO).toString());

    // Step 5: Set the preview output
    mMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mPreview.getHolder().getSurface());

    // Step 6: Prepare configured MediaRecorder
    try {
        mMediaRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "IllegalStateException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "IOException preparing MediaRecorder: " + e.getMessage());
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Media Capture:

```
public static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) {
    return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO));
}

/**
 * Create a File for saving an image or video
 */
public static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {
    // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
    // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.

    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES), "MyApplication");

    // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
    // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.d("MyApplication", "failed to create directory");
            return null;
        }
    }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                    "VID_" + timeStamp + ".mp4");
        } else {
            return null;
        }
        return mediaFile;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I too was very perplexed by this behaviour until I realised unplugging the USB was causing the files to appear. This appears to be a bug in Android, possibly related to this one :

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=195362

Clearly, the file has been written correctly, but for some reason the new file is not visible. In any case, the solution/workaround offered in the link above is to force a media scan of your file. e.g.

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(getContext(), new String[]{this.mediaFile.getAbsolutePath()}, null, null);
```

Where 'mediaFile' is the file your mediaRecorder has just finished writing. With this in place I do not need to unplug the USB cable to see the file and it appears immediately after recording has finished.

I am running Android 5.0.2 on a Samsung Galaxy A5. This feels more of a workaround than a fix and I can't be sure it will work on other devices or Android versions, but I hope it helps someone.